# Simple pagination in my page

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

[image]

Here is the output of my "products.php" page

I've tried several pagination code and adapted it but i am not managing to do it ...
I would really need some help with a easy tutorial or a working code to a pagination.
For example 4 products in each page.

I know its not a bit of code but i dont know where else to ask for help ...

```
<?php

// to prevent undefined index notice
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";

if($action=='add'){
    echo "<div>" . $name . " was added to your cart.</div>";
}

if($action=='exists'){
    echo "<div>" . $name . " already exists in your cart.</div>";
}

require "libs/DbConnect.php";

$query = "SELECT id, name, price FROM products";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){
    echo "<table border='0'>";//start table

        // our table heading
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Price (USD)</th>";
            echo "<th>Action</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignRight'>{$price}</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignCenter'>";
                    echo "<a href='addToCart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='customButton'>";
                        echo "<img src='images/add-to-cart.png' class='imagem2'title='Add To Cart' />";
                    echo "</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";
}

// no products in the database
else{
    echo "No products found.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a page offset as a query string in your url.  From there, you can $_GET the current page offset from the start, and create an offset in your sql query to bypass the products that are supposed to appear on the pages you've already passed.  Also, limit the results to the number of posts you want to see per page.

For example, if you're on page 2, and you're posting 4 products per page, your sql query should limit to 4 returned results, and skip the first 4 results in the table.

Comment: Yeah my php knowladge sucks. I mostly edit code.or only program a bit. Cant you provid just a simple págination working.code? Im kinda desesperated lol

Answer (score 0):

If your interested, I can make you a pagination but using **MySQLi**. Feel free to try this:

Assume that your **DbConnect.php** is like this:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("YourHost","Username","Password","Database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

And your **Pagination** page:

```
<?php

/* I DID NOT ALTER THIS PART OF YOUR ACTION, JUST PASTED IT HERE... */

$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";

if($action=='add'){
    echo "<div>" . $name . " was added to your cart.</div>";
}

if($action=='exists'){
    echo "<div>" . $name . " already exists in your cart.</div>";
}

/* ...UNTIL HERE */

include('libs/DbConnect.php'); /* INCLUDE YOUR CONNECTION */

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name,price FROM products ORDER BY id"); /* EXECUTE YOUR QUERY */

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];

$rowsperpage = 4; /* SET 4 ROWS PER PAGE */
$totalpages = ceil($count / $rowsperpage);

if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
      $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
     $currentpage = 1;
} 

if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} 
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   $currentpage = 1;
} 

$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name,price FROM products ORDER BY id LIMIT $offset,$rowsperpage"); /* EXECUTE QUERY WITH LIMIT */

echo "<table border='0'><tr><th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ /* FETCH ARRAY BASED FROM THE QUERY */

$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['name']); /* ESCAPE STRINGS AND PUT THEM IN A VARIABLE */
$price=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['price']); /* ESCAPE STRINGS AND PUT THEM IN A VARIABLE */

echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td>
<td class='textAlignRight'>".$price."</td>
<td class='textAlignCenter'>
<a href='addToCart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='customButton'>
<img src='images/add-to-cart.png' class='imagem2' title='Add To Cart' />
</a>
</td></tr>";

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

if($count==0){ /* IF NO PRODUCTS FOUND */
echo "<tr><td></td><td>No products found.</td><td></td></tr>";
}

else { /* START OF PAGINATION LINK */

echo '<tr height="30px;" valign="bottom"><td></td><td>';

echo "<table style='border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:3px;'><tr>";


/******  build the pagination links ******/
$range = 2;

if ($currentpage > 1) {
   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
   echo "<td style='width:70px; background-color:fff; border:solid #08c 1px; font-size:14px;' align='center'> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage' style='background-color:fff;'>Previous</a> </td>";
} 


for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {

   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      if ($x == $currentpage) {    
         echo "<td style='width:20px; background-color:fff; font-size:14px; border:solid #ccc 2px;' align='center'> <font color='#ccc'><b>$x</b></font> </td>";
      } else {
         echo "<td style='width:20px; background-color:fff; font-size:14px; border:solid #08c 1px;' align='center'> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x' style='background-color:fff;'>$x</a> </td>";
      } 
   } 
}                  

if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
     echo "<td style='width:70px; background-color:fff; font-size:14px; border:solid #08c 1px;' align='center'> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage' style='background-color:fff;'>Next</a> </td>";

} // end if
/****** end build pagination links ******/

echo "</tr></table></td></tr>";

} /* END OF ELSE IF COUNT 0 */

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: is there any diference using mysqli or mysql??

Comment: @user3689530 - The difference is that MySQL is already deprecated.